# Can jQuery work on in-memory HTML structure?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, typescript

Work on in-memory HTML structure in jQuery.

I have this piece of HTML code:

```
    <div id="template" hidden="hidden">
        <div class="col-md-3 margin-bottom20">
            <p id="template-title" class="text-capitalize"></p>
            <img id="template-image" class="img-responsive" src="#" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <h4>Search Results:</h4>
            <div id="target"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

There is a hidden div element (id = template) which I want us as a temple that is customized and then one or more of these customized temple items are to be put into the div target element (id = target). Think of it as a temple to display search results.
I want to customize the template title and template image and the template image should also get a click event handler.
This is the TypeScript code I have tried:

```
let template: JQuery = $('#template');
let target: JQuery = $('#target');

/* loop simulates search results */
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    let item: JQuery = $($.parseHTML(template[0].innerHTML));

    item.filter('#template-title').html('This is title ' + i.toString());
    item.filter('#template-image').prop('src', '/img/image' + i.toString() + '.png');
    item.filter('#template-image').on('click', () => alert('Clicked on image ' + i.toString()));

    target.append(item);
}
```

I am using jQuery but it looks like the filter statements do not work.
Is it possible to have an in-memory tree structure and work on the with jQuery? Or maybe this can only be done with pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can modify in memory jQuery objects

Several issues however with your approach.

1. You can't repeat ID's in a page so change template items to classes instead
2. Use `find()` not `filter()` since the elements you want are not in the root of the object and are nested deeper

---

Basic non TypeScript example:

```js
let template = $('#template');
let target = $('#target');

/* loop simulates search results */
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  let item = template.children().clone();
  item.find('.template-title').html('This is title ' + i);
  target.append(item);
}
```

```css
.margin-bottom20 { border: 2px solid #ccc; margin-bottom:10px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="template" hidden="hidden">
  <div class="col-md-3 margin-bottom20">
    <p class="template-title text-capitalize"></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <h4>Search Results:</h4>
    <div id="target"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```